# Error with range of NSData

Tags: ios, nsdata

I am using the `CoreBluetooth` framework, where after I have updated a value for a characteristic I get the callback `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` from the peripheral. Here, I found a snippet do decode the data within the `NSData` object returned:

```
- (void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error{

    NSUInteger *flags = (NSUInteger*) [[[characteristic value] subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)] bytes];
    NSUInteger length;
    if(*flags & 0x01)
    {
        length = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        length = 1;
    }
    NSUInteger *measurement = (NSUInteger*) [[[characteristic value] subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, length)] bytes];

    NSLog(@"Value read from char: %d", *measurement);
}
```

Here the code throws an exception:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteData subdataWithRange:]: range {1, 1} exceeds data length 1'`

Could someone explain why? The value I am supposed to read should be 1 byte.

Comment: Where do you send the subdataWithRange: message? The error you describe has nothing to do with the code you show.

Comment: I tried you code and nothing happened. It looks like an "out of index" error, can you post more codes?

Comment: @hago, I found that this happened elsewhere, and did not have anything to do with this snippet. I will update my code where it actually happens.

Comment: 1) The error message indicates that `[characteristic value]` is a data object of length 1, so that accessing the second byte throws an exception. - 2) `NSUInteger *flags = ...` looks *very suspicious*. The right hand side returns a pointer to a buffer of length one, but `NSUInteger *` is a pointer to an 4-byte integer! At least change `NSUInteger *` to `uint8_t *` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, length)` on the `characteristic` you are asking for data that doesn't exist. You should check the length of the `characteristic` before you try to extract data from it. You should also check your logic for how you decide how much data should be in the `characteristic` as that would seem to be invalid.

Comment: why that I see is "NSUInteger *flags = (NSUInteger*) [[[characteristic value] subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)] bytes];", author has updated?